# Why are properties of an immutable object mutable in Swift?

Tags: swift, immutability

In Swift, we denote an immutable variable with `let`.

What I don't understand is why you change their properties. For example:

```
let lbl = UILabel()
lbl.textAlignment = .Right()
```

Why can you change `textAlignment`? By virtue of mutating the property, haven't we also mutated the variable `lbl` that was supposed to be constant?

Comment: The *variable/binding* cannot be re-assigned to a different value; this alone says nothing about the mutability of the object that results from evaluation of the variable. This is the same as `final/readonly` variables/fields in Java and C#.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html), the properties of constant *structs* are also constant, but constant *classes* can have mutable properties.

In their words,

> If you create an instance of a structure and assign that instance to a constant, you cannot modify the instance’s properties, even if they were declared as variable properties...
>
> The same is not true for classes, which are reference types. If you assign an instance of a reference type to a constant, you can still change that instance’s variable properties.

Comment: Thanks, explains it perfectly. Will accept when I can.

Answer (score 3):

Class types are reference types -- the value is a pointer to an object. Not being able to change it simply means not changing the reference, to point to another object. It does not have anything to do with what you can do with the object being pointed to.