# Why are iterators in forEach immutable for a struct but mutable for a class?

Tags: swift, class, struct, foreach, iterator

The iterator is mutable for a class:

```
var selections: [Selection] = []

class Selection {
    var selected: Bool

    init(selected: Bool) {
        self.selected = selected
    }
}

selections.forEach({ $0.selected = false }) // This works
```

but not mutable for a struct:

```
var selections: [Selection] = []

struct Selection {
    var selected: Bool
}

selections.forEach({ $0.selected = false }) // This doesn't work because $0 is immutable
```

Comment: Because classes are *reference types*. The iterator is constant in both cases.

Comment: Compare  [Why are properties of an immutable object mutable in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827643/why-are-properties-of-an-immutable-object-mutable-in-swift).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true, that structures are immutable. But you change a different instance of the  structure.

Swift obfuscates the way objects and structures are treated.

Objects are reference types, structures are value types. That means, that iterating over objects passes a reference to the object as argument and changing the object that the reference points to, is changing the the original object.

Structures are value types. A new instance of the structure is passed as argument. Moreover it is constant in this case. But even if you could change this, this would not effect the original instance of the structure.

In other programming language this different level of indirection is visible, i. e. in Objective-C by an `*`. In Swift it isn't.

Comment: The *"You change this  ... but this does not effect the original ..."* part is misleading .You cannot change `$0` inside the loop in the struct case, because it is a constant.

Comment: Thanks, that `struct` is a value type my first assumption but in [Comparing Classes and Structures] (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID83) it seems not to be listed as a difference between class and struct. However, I just found it is mentioned later on the same page.

Comment: @MartinR Correct, but the story behind is more important. I'll try to clarify that. Thank you!